# Custom control resizing, children rearranging

Tags: javafx

I've created a custom control consisting of an AnchorPane with several labels in it, the control is contained in a SplitPane. Now I have two issues about resizing I can't find solution to

1) I need the custom control to resize according to the parent pane.

2) I need the labels in the custom control to rearrange depending from the custom control size

Comment: Why an `AnchorPane`? This is probably the least capable of automatic layout of all the layout panes.

Comment: Because according to documentation, AnchorPane is the only layout offering relative positioning of children nodes

Comment: `AnchorPane` offers *absolute* positioning of the `Node`s, in the sense that they are all positioned relative to the pane, not relative to each other. You could listen for changes to the bounds of the pane and update all the anchors in response, but it's probably easier to use the pre-built layout panes (or a combination of them). If you give more detail on how you want them laid out I could probably offer suggestions.